# Install Leaflet plugins in Python based environment for web GIS building purpose

Tags: python, leaflet, leaflet-draw, leaflet-plugins, flask

I am in the middle progress of building a webgis that utilize python Flask as backend and Leaflet to build the maps. I can still manage until the step where I implemented the vanilla Leaflet and just show the maps (without the plugins).

For adding further Leaflet capabilities like drawing polygon/polyline/upload shapefile, what I understand is I need to install Leaflet Plugin (https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#edit-geometries) such as Leaflet Draw (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw).

I need this functionality in order to store the polygon or the shapefile into a database (to implement Create Read Update Delete functionalities) where I have chosen PostgreSQL for this purpose.

The installation for Leaflet Draw seem to depends on npm package installer which I dont think it can be used for Python, and this means my backend is going to be with nodeJS, at least from what I understand. My questions:

1. Could such installation of the Leaflet Plugins possible for Python based framework?
2. or if it is not, are there any alternative workaround? I was considering OpenLayers but also unable to figure out installation for Python based framework

Comment: See https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/ and https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/reference.html#module-folium.plugins

Comment: @TomazicM ah thanks for the folium leaflet wrap hint, feels like I could try with the workaround now. appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use leaflet-draw in python, maybe you should use datasette-leaflet-freedraw
[enter link description here](https://pypi.org/project/datasette-leaflet-freedraw/)